# Is the time of suffering of the woman with hemorrhage related to the daughter of the Jew Jairus?

Tags: woman

The twelve years that a woman had a hemorrhage in Matthew 9:20-22 and Luke 8:43-48 has some bearing on the twelve years of the daughter of Jairus Matthew 9:18-26; Mark 5:21-43; Luke 8:40-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two stores concerning the daughter of Jairus and the woman with the issue of blood have many similarities including:

- Both Women needed to be healed
- Both desperate
- Both sought Jesus
- Both put their faith in Him
- Both are healed
- Both associated with 12-year period
- Both “Daughters”
- Both had not no legal or social status

However, there are some significant differences between the two stories:

- One condition was chronic and the other acute
- One had an advocate 9the father) and the other approached Jerus personally
- One was a mature woman and the other was a girl
- One was healed by a word from Jesus and the other was healed by touching Jesus' garment
- One was (ceremonially speaking) illegal and the other was legal
- One Jesus healed consciously and the other was "unconsciously", ie, without an explicit decision to do so
- One was alive and the other dead
- Jesus spoke to one before the healing/resurrection and to the other only after the healing

The lessons we draw from these exquisitely crafted stores are many but here are a few that I might understand:

- some cases look similar but are actually quite different.  That does not matter - Jesus still loved them both and ministered to them both.
- The woman's faith was immature and somewhat superstitious; but Jesus healed her anyway.  That is, we do not need a perfect faith for Jesus to act.  Put another way, faith is not a work we do to earn God's favor because He loves us already.
- Sometimes Jesus' apparent inaction (the delay resulting in the girl's death) results in a greater miracle, resurrection from the dead in this case.
- Despite the people laughing at Jesus (Mark 5:40), Jesus still acted, again emphasizing that Jesus does not require perfect faith.  This is very comforting because none of us has perfect faith.
- Despite the "press" of the crowd, Jesus could tell the difference in the touch of faith vs the common push of the crowd - only the woman was healed and none else in the crowd.